# adding labels to 2D scatter plot (kmeans clustering)

Tags: r

I calculated PCA on the samples of my dataset and retained the first two components vectors .I then calculated k-means clustering on these first two components with k=3.
Now I need to plot a 2D scatter plot with the first two eigenfunctions (from PCA) and color based on the cluster group. I accomplished everything with the scatter plot but when I look at the plot I cannot differentiate which samples are clustered so I want to add the sample labels to the points in scatter plot.
Can anybody suggest me how to go about this?

```
tdata<-t(subdata)
pca <- prcomp((tdata),cor=F)
dat.loadings <-pca$x[,1:2]
cl <- kmeans(dat.loadings, centers=3)
pca1 <-pca$x[,1]
pca2 <-pca$x[,2]
plot(pca1, pca2,xlab="PCA-1",ylab="PCA-2",col=cl$cluster)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done simply using ggplot. I will use the mtcars data since I don't have access to the dataset you are currently using. The idea should be pretty clear anyway.

```
library(ggplot2)
pca <- prcomp((mtcars),cor=F)
dat.loadings <-pca$x[,1:2]
cl <- kmeans(dat.loadings, centers=3)
pca1 <-pca$x[,1]
pca2 <-pca$x[,2]
#plot(pca1, pca2,xlab="PCA-1",ylab="PCA-2",col=cl$cluster)
mydf<-data.frame(ID=names(pca1),PCA1=pca1, PCA2=pca2, Cluster=factor(cl$cluster))
ggplot(mydf, aes(x=PCA1, y=PCA2, label=ID, color=Cluster)) + 
       geom_point() + geom_text(size = 4, colour = "black", vjust = -1)
```

This gives you a names output per data point.

[image: Plot of the results]